# Best practices for mongodb indexes on multiple fields

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

In mongodb I have a certain collection (Invoice), and throughout our application we query for invoices and filter by many different fields like so:

```
public static List<Invoice> FindAll(string userId, Enums.InvoiceType? type = null, string propertyId = null, 
            string tenantId = null, string landlordId = null, string ownerUserId = null, 
            bool? isClosed = null, bool? autoGenerated = null, DateTime? startDate = null, DateTime? endDate = null,
            int? skip = null, int? take = null) {
            var builder = Filter;
            var filters = builder.Eq("UserId", userId.ToObjectId());
            if (type.HasValue)
                filters = filters & builder.Eq("Type", type.Value);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyId))
                filters = filters & builder.Eq("PropertyId", propertyId.ToObjectId());
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tenantId))
                filters = filters & builder.Eq("TenantId", tenantId.ToObjectId());
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(landlordId))
                filters = filters & builder.Eq("LandlordId", landlordId.ToObjectId());
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ownerUserId))
                filters = filters & builder.Eq("OwnerUserId", ownerUserId.ToObjectId());
            if (isClosed.HasValue)
                filters = filters & builder.Eq("IsClosed", isClosed.Value);
            if (autoGenerated.HasValue)
                filters = filters & builder.Eq("AutoGenerated", autoGenerated.Value);
            if (startDate.HasValue)
                filters = filters & builder.Gte("DueDate", startDate.Value);
            if (endDate.HasValue)
                filters = filters & builder.Lte("DueDate", endDate.Value);

            var result = Collection().Find(filters)
                .Sort(Builders<Invoice>.Sort.Descending("DueDate"));
            if (skip.HasValue)
                result.Skip(skip.Value);
            if (take.HasValue)
                result.Limit(take.Value);
            return result.ToList();
        }
```

Because there are so many fields that we filter on, I created separate indexes for each filterable field:

```
db.Invoice.ensureIndex( { UserId: 1 } );
db.Invoice.ensureIndex( { Type: 1 } );
db.Invoice.ensureIndex( { PropertyId: 1 } );
db.Invoice.ensureIndex( { TenantId: 1 } );
db.Invoice.ensureIndex( { LandlordId: 1 } );
db.Invoice.ensureIndex( { OwnerUserId: 1 } );
db.Invoice.ensureIndex( { DueDate: 1 } );
db.Invoice.ensureIndex( { AutoGenerated: 1 } );
```

However, today I noticed that when filtering by UserId, Type, and TenantId (in one query), it was taking ~750ms. As soon as I created the following index:

```
db.Invoice.ensureIndex( { UserId: 1, Type: 1, TenantId: 1 } );
```

...the query started taking ~15ms. So clearly, creating indexes on each separate field that will be filtered isn't performant when the queries filter on multiple fields (using multiple indexes.) However, I can't possibly create indexes for every permutation of the queries that will be performed.

What is the solution? Should I only have one index that is on every filterable field? (I'll have to test to see how it performs, but it seems wrong.)

Answer (score 1):

A good practice to keep in mind when doing any `Find` operations is to index against  what your `Find` is doing.

Your `Find` that you mentioned above is most likely doing a collection scan because it cannot find a suitable index to use from your collection and has to traverse the entire collection to satisfy your requested operation hence why your slow performance.

My advice would be to trawl your codebase for all finds against your invoice collection and setup relevant indexes for them. That way when the `Find` operation runs mongodb will use the most appropriate index to satisfy the operation. It is also recommended by Mongo as per their [Indexing Strategies](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/)

In your scenario I would suggest using a [Compound Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/) because you are looking up against multiple fields. Be careful of the order of your index aswell, mongo will look at the first item in the index . I would advise matching your query order to your indexing strategy to gain the best performance.

If you are trying to avoid having to setup an index specifically for a `Find` I suggest using the compound index and index only the most common properties you normally query on in your code base. They are able to satisfy a wider range of queries.